# How do I get Python and Selenium to click an angularjs link by matching the link to user input text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs, selenium

The link I would like to click is input by the user.  For example the user inputs for variable **track**, "Tampa Bay Downs"

My python selenium test program will search the code below:

```
<a ng-click="updateFavorite()(raceInfo.trackAbbr); $event.stopPropagation();">EV
  i class="my-icon-favorite-fill my-icon-favorite-fill_active" ng-class="{
  'my-icon-favorite-fill' : !showActionFeedback, ...onFeedback, 'rotating spinner' :
  showActionFeedback}" update-favorite-action-feedback="" qa-label="race-favorite-icon">
    ::before
   </i>
</a>
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="::raceInfo.trackName" qa-label="race-track-name">
Tampa Bay Downs</span>
</td>
```

The successful code will find the input words "Tampa Bay Downs" and then click it to activate an angularjs action that would cause a separate page to open, which is the desired action.

I have tried to find the link using the correct xpath with no success.
I have also tried this with no success:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[qa-label="+track+"]")
except:
    print "error finding css selector for track"
```

Comment: You can try by xpath with `"//span[contains(.,'{}')]/preceding-sibling::a".format(track)` or use the class name to be more specific `"//span[@qa-label='race-track-name' and contains(.,'{}')]/preceding-sibling::a".format(track)`

Comment: Also don't use blanket except statements, catch what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply (and suggestion) Padraic, I'm giving that a try now.

Comment: It worked.  If you send your answer as an answer, I will check it.  Many thanks!

Comment: No worries, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select using an `xpath` using *preceding-sibling*  to find the `a` before the span tag that contains the track name i.e *Tampa Bay Downs*:

```
"//span[contains(.,'{}')]/preceding-sibling::a".format(track)
```

Or more specifically using the span class name:

```
 "//span[@qa-label='race-track-name' and contains(.,'{}')]/preceding-sibling::a".format(track)
```